# JAXB xjc tool and non-ascii characters

Tags: jaxb, xjc, non-ascii-characters

I have an xsd scheme which contains non-ascii characters.

I want to generate classes but force the xjc tool NOT to convert those characters to unicode format (\uXXXX), and just leave them as is.

Trouble is when it puts a value of enum in unicode representation to XmlEnumValue annotation of generated class, JAXB unmarshaler can't map appropriate fields. When I manually convert it to plain state, it works ok.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

You could use this code to convert characters in the file back to native representation:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils;

public void convertToNative(String filePath) throws IOException {
    File file = new File(filePath);
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(filePath + ".converted");
    try {
        String s = FileUtils.readFileToString(file, "utf-8");
        s = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(s);
        writer.write(s);
    } finally {
        writer.close();
    }
}
```